# Find beacons in background mode iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, beacon

I want to find AXABeacons in background mode. I know that I must have a good reason to let Apple approve the application but I wonder if it's possible to rang beacons in background mode. Have anybody done that before?

Comment: Ya we can. Select target than go to "Capabilities" and enable the "Background Mode" than check the "Background fetch".

Comment: I checked it but i do not give any effect, is there any method i need to implement? @SandeepKumar